# Anchor a view at the bottom of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm building a view which is a `UITableView`, however I want to anchor a "Write a comment" `UITextField` at the bottom of the screen.  You can see an example of this on these screenshots from the "Secret" app - the "Write a comment (anonymously)" and "Post" button are anchored to the bottom of the screen regardless of whether you scroll the tableview items up or down.

[image]

[image]

What's the best way to achieve this?

Should I be embedding a `UITableViewController` into a `UIViewController` with the `UIView` anchored to the bottom of the screen and the tableview anchored to the top of this view?

Is this some kind of `UITableView` section footer?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is this terrible ad doing in the middle of this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `UITableView` and add a bottom view (not to confuse with a tableview's `footerView`). Since a `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, you can change its `contentInsets` so that the content of the tableview will still scroll above your bottom view.

`tableView.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, bottomViewHeight);`

The next step would be to make the bottom view sticky, that is, floating with the bottom of the tableview. You can achieve this in multiple ways. Here are two suggestions:

### 1) Manipulating the frame directly

By conforming to `UITableViewDelegate` you automatically conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. You can see this by inspecting the protocol declaration in `UITableView.h`:

`@protocol UITableViewDelegate<NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate>`

Then implement `scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` and change the y-offset of the bottomview to always position it at the bottom of the view. `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset` property is used to determine how far down the scrollview has scrolled. This method will be called every single time the scrollview scrolls, hence it will appear that the bottom view sticks to the bottom of the tableview.

### 2) Use auto layout

While still changing the `contentInsets` as above, you can achieve the sticky effect by using auto layout constraints instead. By pinning the bottom view to the edge of the scrollview, it will automatically create the sticky effect for you. This is by far my recommended approach, since it saves lines of code, while it uses the highest possible level of abstraction.

---

I use [this category](https://github.com/dkduck/FLKAutoLayout) by [Florian Kugler](http://floriankugler.com) when implementing auto layout in code.

[This technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html), however not strictly related to the issue, describes how to use auto layout with scrollviews.

Comment: But how do you add a bottom view to the tableview?

Answer (score 1):

I have in-app chat (like whatsapp) and I have the following structure:

```
UIViewController
\
 - View
    \
     - UITableView
     - UIView (with textfied)
```

I thinks this is the best approach as you don't mix table data with anything else, and you don't have to juggle with sections in code

Comment: Hi! How you managed to move the content up and display the text field when the keyboard is shown?

Answer (score 0):

if you requirement is to show only one picture related information at once in screen means please follow the process it will help you.

first take a view controller then take an image view and on it the buttons you needed add them on image view only below image view take a tableview(if there are comments show tableview. if no comments available show a label as"be first to comment").

Hope this will help